# azure-function-cli func run <FunctionName> only returns "Response Status Code : NotFound"

Tags: azure-functions

When I run this command the local server starts and I am able to call my functions with cURL in PowerShell, but the func run  command always seems to return Response Status Code: NotFound.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running func run in the directory where you have host.json?

Comment: @lindydonna-msft thanks for the comment.  I am. I just realized I am following your tutorial here.  'Running Azure Functions Locally with the CLI and VS Code'  Most of which is working well for me

Comment: I think I have narrowed down the cause.  It seems that restricting the http methods in the function.json file such as "methods": ["get" ].  Is causing a problem

Comment: @lindydonna-msft any idea why the methods property is causing that?

Comment: Does the same code work in the Azure portal?

Comment: The same code works in azure portal as well as when using cURL from PowerShell after having called func run

Comment: Interesting, what happens if you run "func host start" first?

Comment: The behavior is the same.  It seems restricting the http methods is causing the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report!  Feel free to answer your own question to help out others. Link here for reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/82

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is expected behavior. The `func run` command does only a simple HTTP POST, as we didn't want to reinvent all the functionality in cURL. We're going to print a warning in the future so that customers know that the functionality is limited: [When using func run with http trigger, print a warning #85](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-cli/issues/85).